# Animate multiple objects at same instance with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am working on following requirements.

1. Have all the sections of the website on single page
2. Display only one section at one instance
3. When user clicks on the link to visit another section -- have a smooth scrolling effect to reach that section.

Here's a fiddle to what I have achieved so far
http://jsfiddle.net/karuna/eqCYE/1/

**And here's my code**

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
    //On page load hide all but the first section
$("#wrapper div[id!=red]").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass("hide");
});   

$("#mainNav a").click( function(){
    var nextSection = $(this).attr("href");
    var currentSection = $("#mainNav a.active").attr("href");

    //If link to current section clicked -- Do NOTHING
    if (currentSection == nextSection){
        return;
    }        

    else{
        //All good to slide to the section

        //Start with assigning active on nav items
        $("#mainNav a").each( function(){
            if($(this).attr("href") == nextSection){
                $(this).addClass("active");
            }
            else{
                $(this).removeClass("active");
            }
        }); 

        //Make the nextSection visible
        $(nextSection).removeClass("hide");

        //Construct an array to compute position of sections on DOM 
        var positions = new Array();
        counter =0;
        $("#mainNav a").each(function(){
            positions[counter] = $(this).attr("href");
            counter++;
        });

        //Function to compute position of an element in an array
        Array.prototype.position = function (s) {
            var i = 0;
            while (i < this.length && this [i] != s) {i++};
            return i < this.length ? i : undefined;
        }

        //If currentSection is below nextSection
        if(positions.position(currentSection) > positions.position(nextSection)){   
            $(nextSection).css("top", "-200px");
            $(currentSection).css ("top", "0px");                      
                   $(nextSection).animate({              
                         top: '0px'
                        }, { queue: false, duration: 1000 } );
                    $(currentSection).animate({              
                         top: "200px"
                        }, { queue: false, duration: 1000 });    

        }
        else if(positions.position(currentSection) < positions.position(nextSection)){  
            $(nextSection).css("top", "200px");
            $(currentSection).css ("top", "0px");                      
                   $(nextSection).animate({      
                         top: '0px'
                        }, { queue: false, duration: 1000 } );
                    $(currentSection).animate({              
                         top: "-200px"
                        }, { queue: false, duration: 1000 });   

        }   
        $(nextSection).css("top", "");
        $(currentSection).css ("top", "");  
        $(currentSection).addClass("hide");
    }       
})
});
```

**HTML**

```
<nav id="mainNav">
<a href="#red" class="active">Red</a>
<a href="#blue">Blue</a>
<a href="#green">Green</a>
<a href="#orange">Orange</a>
</nav>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="red"></div>
    <div id="blue"></div>
    <div id="green"></div>
    <div id="orange"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#mainNav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
#mainNav a.active{
    color: red;
}
div{
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
div>div{
    position: relative;
}
#wrapper{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: grey;
}   
#red{
    background: red;
}   
#blue{
    background: blue;
}   
#green{
    background: green;
}   
#orange{
    background: orange;
}

.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

**Problem is:** while scrolling from one section to another, the previous section is not visible.

Can anyone help me on figuring out **why the two animate function do not execute at the same time**. I have added "queue: false" on both of them!!